# new YouTube APIs for Google TV app development?

Tags: google-tv

In terms of the news for the new YouTube Player API for Android and the YouTube Data API v3, can we use these APIs to develop a native Google TV app?  I understand that it would be since the min version for Player API is 2.2 and Google TV runs 3.0 and above but I just wanted to be 100% sure.

And would the Google TV VideoPlayer sample code be a wise template to use when connecting to these new APIs to test it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We announced support for Google TV at Google I/O - And it works now. https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/